# Postgres: process each record of a growing table exactly once

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

We have a growing database of events, each of which has a uuid primary key. Only `INSERTs` are done on that `event` table. No record is ever updated nor deleted.

That table is part of a bigger system and can't be modified. I'm allowed to add indices to it, however.

```sql
create table event (
  id uuid primary key,
  type varchar(50),
  payload jsonb
);

insert into event (uuid, type, payload) values ($1, $2, $3);
```

Events with specific `types` must be aggregated incrementally. In the past I could simply make a big materialized view. But now the volume is such that I can't do that anymore, and I will have to process events one by one. Actually near-realtime would be appreciated.

Events that need to be processed must be processed only once, otherwise my aggregation falls apart.

I considered the following options:

1. add a trigger to my `event` table, and copy events to be processed to another table until they are actually processed. I don't want to do that, because an error in the trigger could prevent insertion into the `event` table. We can't lose any event.
2. rely on some timestamp/serial to order the records. All those attempts resulted in missed records because of other delays in the system (network failures, for example).

One easy way to accomplish that "process exactly once" goal would be to store the uuid of every processed event into a table. I could then query the table to check whether a certain event has been processed or not.

```sql
create table processed_event (
  id uuid primary key
);
```

But then this happens: I have a table with uuids, and an index with the same uuids. Basically, I've just duplicated my data. And it does take a sizeable amount of disk space, about 2GB on my old snapshot (after vacuum full).

```
                    objectname                    | objecttype |   entries   |  size   
--------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------
 processed_event                                  | r          | 2.49663e+07 | 1054 MB
 processed_event_pkey                             | i          | 2.49662e+07 | 751 MB
```

So I'm not sure how this solution is going to scale. At the moment, with the production database, that would be > 5GB of data just to store the processed events.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any other way I could make sure I'm not processing twice the same record?
2. Any chance I could get rid of the `processed_event` table and keep only the `processed_event_pkey` index?
3. Any suggestion?

**Solution**

Answers from Laurenz and Jerrad below are helpful. Too bad I can only validate one...

It's likely that we'll end up with a trigger on the `event` table that inserts new event IDs into a `processed_event` table.

```sql
create table processed_event (
  id uuid primary key,
  processed_at timestamp
)
```

Until the event is processed, the timestamp will be null.

This will allow:

- fast selection of unprocessed events
- debugging/monitoring the processing progress
- reprocessing of events if the aggregations change after initial processing. Simply set `processed_at` to null.

Comment: I would suggest you investigate Transaction Blocks. They are very handy for ensuring that: 

1. changes are aborted if an error occurs.
2. changes to multiple tables happen simultaneously

Comment: I know about transactions, but how is that going to help me scale up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a new table

```
CREATE TABLE materialized_event_count (
   type varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
   count bigint NOT NULL
);
```

(assuming that the aggregate you are interested in is the count per `type`)

Then you can add a trigger to event that

- inserts an entry in `materialized_event_count` or adds one for the appropriate `type` whenever a row in inserted
- subtracts one from the corresponding entry if a row is deleted (delete the row if the count reaches 0)
- does both of the above for an update that changes `type`
- truncates `materialized_event_count` whenever `event` is truncated

Comment: We decided against using triggers because an error in the trigger procedure could prevent the event from being inserted. And since we legally can't lose any of those events, we don't want to take a chance.

Unless there's a way to create a trigger that can fail silently and not block the insert?

Comment: I don't understand - you said yourself that *"I considered the following options: 1. add a trigger to my `event` table"*. You *always* have to live with the option that an `INSERT` fails, e.g. because disk space runs out. If you cannot lose events, you have to cache them in the front-end anyway, right? A well-written trigger won't increase the risk of failure during insret.

Comment: Yes, we can cope with failed inserts (courtesy of rabbitmq), but that doesn't mean we want to add more ways to fail. Increasing disk space is relatively easy, but debugging a trigger while everything is failing is a lot more stressful and risky. I'm curious though: how would you write such a "fail proof" trigger?

Comment: Get inspired by the trigger solution from my [blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/). Of course such a trigger needs testing, like all other software, but it is rather simple code.

Comment: That's an interesting blog post, thanks for sharing! I don't see any error handling in the trigger though. Is there any that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The trigger needs no error handling. If one of the SQL statements in it fails, the trigger (and the statement that caused it) fail, which is exactly what you need to maintain consistency. Relax, the trigger won't increase the likelihood of failure, unless it is buggy.

Comment: In your blog post, you mention the following: "Even though this counter table might receive a lot of updates, there is no danger of “table bloat” because these will all be HOT updates.". I read on other blogs that HOT updates were disabled in version 11.1, but I can find no information about later versions. Does that exist in recent versions of postgres?

Comment: Don't trust blog posts (except mine). HOT is **not** disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with your `processed_event` table.  You can either keep track of when you process an event (in which case your table will grow at the same rate as your `event` table), or you can keep track of which events you still need to process (and you can delete the rows as they are processed).  Personally, I like having a record of what happened and when it happened, and disk space is cheap, so I would go with the first option.  I like the idea of inserting a row into `processed_event` whenever a row is inserted into `event`, and then updating a `date_processed` field when the event is actually processed.  That way you can easily find the list of events that still need to be processed by selecting the rows where `date_processed` is null (and if anyone wants to know when an event was processed, you can tell them).

If you have access to the process that inserts records into the `event` table, you could modify it to also insert a record into the `processed_event` table.  Otherwise, you could make friends with a trigger.  You can write a trigger so that exceptions are handled and in the event of an error, the row is still inserted into the table.  Here is an example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6952b/2).

Another option would be to populate your `processed_event` table like this:

```
insert into processed_event(id)
select id
from event
where id not in (select id from processed_event)
```

You could run that on a schedule depending on how real-time you need to process event.

Comment: It may be a good idea to track more information about processed events indeed, if only to debug/monitor the processing. Disk space is cheap indeed, but IOPS is not, and I'm wondering how much this is going to cost in the long term.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add new attribute "processed" to table "event" and use it as an indication, that record was processed (use index for that column)?

Then based on processed attribute, you can move records to new table event_backup to increase speed of the system, because with growing number of rows, the system will be slower and slower.

Comment: The `event` table can't be modified. It's all part of a bigger system on which I want to have zero impact if possible.